# R error: "select" function error: select(-c())

Tags: r, dplyr

Basically, I was using my `select()` function well like 30 mins before.

But it suddenly doesn't work

I literally have no idea and restart the R like 100 times and re-run the code, but doesn't work

Please help me

[image]

Comment: Try `select(-Order)` or `dplyr::select(-Order)`